Я пытаюсь загрузить библиотеку на PyPI, но не могу вставить токен
Для загрузки я использовал команду:
twine upload dist\*

Вывод такой:
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Enter your API token:

Проблема в том, что я пытаюсь что-либо написать или вставить, но ничего не происходит.
Я думал, что текст просто не видно для безопасности, но я вставил туда токен, а вывод был такой:
WARNING  Error during upload. Retry with the --verbose option for more details.

ERROR    HTTPError: 403 Forbidden from https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
     Invalid or non-existent authentication information. See https://pypi.org/help/#invalid-auth for more information.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Смотри, возможно не работает, т.к. в консоли клавиши немного другие,
Если ты вставлял через ctrl + v, попробуй использовать ctrl + shift + v

Да, винда любит то перевод строки в конце вставить, то ещё чего.

Если что это у меня происходило, только когда я на линукс перешел
